# Do I need to glue down linoleum flooring?

Tags: flooring, linoleum

I am installing a new linoleum floor in a small bathroom (approx. 6' X 6').  This is a replacement for an old linoleum floor.  The replacement will be a single piece.

Talking with the local big box store flooring expert, he recommended **not** gluing it down.

It would be tempting to not glue it down since the linoleum floor will be a single piece and will be held down on all sides.  But while I would love to make things easier for myself and not use glue, I am not so sure this is a good idea.

Would it be a bad idea to not glue down the linoleum floor?

Comment: Did the "expert" say why not to glue it down?

Comment: Not really... just that it is held down on all sides.  Sounds like you are skeptical, just like me.

Comment: I'd be afraid of wrinkles and/or bubbles developing over time.

Comment: What are the manufacture's installation recommendations?

Answer (score 12):

There is a whole new generation of fiberglass, not vinyl, flooring that is self laying. The various manufacturers say it will lay flat, not curl or bubble without adhesive. I have my doubts, but admit I have not used it without adhesive. The manufacturer does says that when adhesive is used, it can only be "Releasable Pressure Sensitive Adhesive", never standard vinyl sheet goods adhesive.

In a small room like you have, I'd test the no glue theory. If it doesn't work well, it's easy enough to go back and glue it down with pressure sensitive adhesive.

Comment: Exactly, apply glue later if you think it's needed.  Easier to apply glue later than try to remove it.

Comment: Very old question but I want to point out that the original post was about linoleum, which is not vinyl. They are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the right vinyl flooring that does not require glue/adhesive and you do decide to use the adhesive make sure it is the releasable pressure sensitive adhesive.  Good luck

Answer (score 0):

The "free floating" sheet vinyl works fine, I've laid it a few times and have never had a complaint...pretty quick and easy as well.  If you want to use an adhesive, which is most likely the smart thing to do for added longevity and protection against natural movement/wrinkles, you do not want to perimeter adhere.  You must use adhesive over the entire subfloor for it to properly lay.  And, as previous posts have mentioned, with the fiberglass backing you must use a pressure sensitive adhesive.

Comment: Saying you've "never had a complaint" is meaningless justification. Most people don't complain when things go wrong, especially if its months down the line after the workmen have left site.

Comment: Very old question but I want to point out that the original post was about linoleum, which is not vinyl. They are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

With the fiberglass free-laying lino we always glue the perimeter. Have also always used the 3M brand spray adhesive for this.